# CursorAdapter dynamic sorting

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview, android-location, android-cursoradapter

I currently use a `CursorAdapter` with a `Loader`. The data loaded by the `Loader` contains a location. I want to order my items from the nearest to the farthest. I already compute the distance to display it, I now need to find a way to dynamicaly sort the data.

I could probably modify the `CursorLoader` sort everytime my data change, but doing the same SQL query again and again just to change the order looks somehow overkill to me…

Is there any way to dynamically sort data in a `CursorAdapter`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `sortOrder` - last parameter of [CursorLoader's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) contructor.

Let's assume your table has column named `lat` for latitude and `lon` for longitude. User's location also described via latitude/longitude `userLat` and `userLon`. For sorting we aren't need to know precise distance - approximate distance will be enough. For that You can use Pythagorean theorem.

`sortOder` will be like this: `abs(lat - userLat)* abs(lat - userLat) + abs(lon-userLon)*abs(lon-userLon)`. This computation contains only supported by Sqlite operators.

Note 1: you have to change code above in order to provide correct String where `userLat` and `userLon` are replaced with their values.

Note 2: you can't use this formula to compute precise distance.

Comment: Totally useful when trying to sort a cursor loader result based on distance